# Why can't you measure the ion temperature with a Langmuir probe?

Tags: plasma-physics

From the I-V curve of a Langmuir probe, the curvature in the ion saturation region (negative voltage) is due to the electron temperature (assuming maxwellian distribution). Similarly in Merlino's paper Understanding Langmuir probe current-voltage characteristics, the curvature in the electron saturation region (positive voltage) would be caused by the finite ion temperature.

This equation shows the ion current as a function of the probe potential. $V_B$ is the probe voltage, $V_p$ is the plasma potential and $T_i$ the ion temperature.

[image: Ion temperature]

He also shows the contributions of the electron current and ion current on a generated I-V curve from the current equations. In his example, the ion current is a lot smaller than the electron current so the ion contribution is so small that the curvature due to the ion temperature appears as a sharp knee.

[image: I-V curve]

In Chen's mini course on Langmuir probe you can read "From the I-V curve, the plasma density $n$, electron temperature $KT_e$, and plasma potential $V_s$ can be determined, but not the ion temperature."

Merlino also says "As a consequence, it is impossible to use the probe
to determine the ion temperature [...]".

In practice, I have seen some I-V curve with curvature at high positive voltages. If you could see the curvature instead of a sharp knee, would you be able to measure the ion temperature? I know a Ball-Pen probe can reduce the electron flux which could reveal the curvature due to the ion temperature. Is there any condition where can you measure the ion temperature from the I-V curve of a standard Langmuir probe? Does any sheath condition prevent the measurement of the ion temperature?

Sources:

- [Lecture Notes on Langmuir Probe Diagnostics, Francis F. Chen (Mini-Course on Plasma Diagnostics, IEEE-ICOPS meeting, Jeju, Korea, 2003)](https://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Effchen/Publs/Chen210R.pdf)
- [Robert L. Merlino; Understanding Langmuir probe current-voltage characteristics. American Journal of Physics 1 December 2007; 75 (12): 1078–1085. https://doi.org/10.1119/1.2772282](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/75/12/1078/899100/Understanding-Langmuir-probe-current-voltage?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

Answer (score 0):

Good day, yes, the Langmuir probe I-V (positive branch) is not suitable for the ion temperature measurements (very high electron current in comparison to the ion current). The ball-pen probe is reducing this electron current to the level of the ion current and thus it can be used to detect the knee and estimate the ion temperature from the I-V as shown in:
J. Adamek et al 2021 Nucl. Fusion 61 036023( https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-4326/abd41d )
D Cipciar et al 2022 Plasma Phys. Control. Fusion 64 055021 ( https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6587/ac5a0b )